# UILocalNotification with action button

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I create a UILocationNotification with two action button one call sleep and wake up now. So once the user sees the notification if they pressed wake up now the app will launch and execute some code **for some reason the app launches then refuse to execute the codes**.

> FYI : The code for the UILocalNotification were implement and they are working, the only problem is when I pressed the wake up now button.

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification, completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    if notification.category == "options" {
     if identifier == "Sleep"{

         println("sleep more lazy bumm")
      }
    else if identifier == "wakeup"{
        var object = ViewController()
          object.wakeupnow()

     }
    }
```

Second Approach I took but it still not working

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification, completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    if notification.category == "options" {
     if identifier == "Sleep"{

         println("sleep more lazy bumm")
      }
    else if identifier == "wakeup"{
          NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("wake"), name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)

     }
    }

   fun wake(){
      var alertview = UIAlertView()
      alert.message = "Good job you are up now, so lets get to work"
      alert.addButtonWithTitle("ok")
      alert.cancelButtonIndex = 0 
      alert.show()
     }
```

Comment: what is the actual error?

Comment: there is no error for some reason the code was not called

Answer (score 0):

Remember that application:handleActionWithIdentifer:forLocalNotification:completionHandler: gets called in a background thread. If you're doing anything in the UI you'll need to do it on the main queue.

Also, you have to call the completionHandler block as soon as you can, or the system will kill your app.

Please see the Apple documentation about this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:

Also, in your first example you are instantiating a view controller and calling a function on it but you aren't actually presenting the view controller - what do you want to happen with that view controller? You'll need to do something to make it appear, which will depend on how your app is structured. You may want to present it modally over your root navigation controller, for example. Or maybe you mean to be calling that function on your already-existing ViewController, in which case you need to keep a reference to it somewhere instead of instantiating a new one when the notification action is triggered.

In your second example, you are adding yourself as an observer to the NSNotificationCenter instead of actually posting a notification, so of course your function will never get called. If you want to take that approach, you need to call `addObserver` sometime earlier - in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, for example:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("wake"), name: "wakeup", object: nil)
```

Then, in your `handleActionWithIdentifier:` function, call:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("wakeup", object: nil)
```

That should result in your `wake` function being called. You still have the problem of trying to show an alert view from a background thread, though, so you would need to wrap your call in a dispatch_async:

```
func wake(){
  var alertview = UIAlertView()
  alert.message = "Good job you are up now, so lets get to work"
  alert.addButtonWithTitle("ok")
  alert.cancelButtonIndex = 0 
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
     alert.show()
  })
 }
```

Incidentally, UIAlertView is deprecated and should be replaced by UIAlertController for iOS 8 and up.

Comment: I did read this document. what approach you will take to solve this ?

Comment: In your first example you are creating a ViewController and calling a function on it but you aren't actually presenting the view controller - what do you want to happen with it? You'll need to do something to make it appear, which will depend on how your app is structured. You may want to present it modally over your root navigation controller, for example. Or maybe you mean to be calling that function on your already-existing ViewController, in which case you need to keep a reference to it somewhere instead of instantiating a new one when the notification action is triggered.

Comment: yeah i Knew the first approach was not right.. that why i try the second approach

Comment: In your second example you have several problems - please see the updated part of my answer for information.

Comment: let say I wanted to call another function in another view controller: **let object = ViewController** then **object.wakeup()** inside of the dispatch code **but for some reason the code crash saying**  **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**